# Starting React server

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have written my react app and when I run `npm start` it does bring  `'GENERATE_SOURCEMAP' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file.`. I'm using windows 10.  Can someone help me with solving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My crystal ball says your `package.json`'s `"scripts"` has something like

```
"start": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts start"
```

to set the `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP` environment variable, which would be fine with POSIX shells such as those used by macOS and Linux, but in Windows's command processor.

To run on Windows, you will need to get rid of the `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false` there; if you do want to set the environment variable, do it manually first.

```
> set GENERATE_SOURCEMAP false
> npm start
```

The other easy option is to add e.g. [`cross-env`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env), and do `cross-env GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts start`.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by creating file `.env.production` and putting `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false` there... then you can simply run just `react-scripts start`